# I am trying to display data in react but i get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I receive data in react using axios but when i try to map through it i get an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" I was trying to find solutions to this and i think that react first renders the page before setting the data, I also tried looping thorugh the data manually or using forEach but still got a variation of the errors below.
For some reason it also returns 3 similar errors every time it runs

Code:

```
import axios from "axios";

function Table() {

let [backendData, setData] = useState();


async function getData(){
  await axios.get("table")
  .then(response => response.data)
  .then(data => setData(data))
}

useEffect(() => {
getData();
}, [])





return(
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Child's Name</th>
          <th>Child's Age</th>
          <th>Room No.</th>
          <th>Parent/Guardian Location</th>
          <th>Parent/Guardian Signature In</th>
          <th>Staff Signature In</th>
          <th>Parent/Guardian Signature Out</th>
          <th>Staff Signature Out</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

            {backendData.map(child => {
              <tr key={child._id}>
                <td>{child.childName}</td>
                <td>{child.childAge}</td>
                <td>{child.roomNumber}</td>
                <td>temporary</td>
                <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
                <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
                <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
                <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
              </tr> 
            })}

    </table>
  </div>
  ) 

}

export default Table;
```

Error:

````
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
   at Table (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2183:29)
   at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24189:22)
   at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:27475:17)
   at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28771:20)
   at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:13781:18)
   at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:13825:20)
   at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:13882:35)
   at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33756:11)
   at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33003:16)
   at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32926:9)
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
   at Table (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2183:29)
   at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24189:22)
   at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:27475:17)
   at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28771:20)
   at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:13781:18)
   at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:13825:20)
   at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:13882:35)
   at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33756:11)
   at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33003:16)
   at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32926:9)
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
   at Table (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2183:29)
   at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24189:22)
   at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:27475:17)
   at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28771:20)
   at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33734:18)
   at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33003:16)
   at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32926:9)
   at renderRootSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32899:11)
   at recoverFromConcurrentError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32391:24)
   at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32303:26)```
````

Comment: `const [backendData, setData] = useState([]);`

Comment: Your data call is asynchronous, so `backendData` starts as empty the way you have it now, just initialize it to `[]` in your `useState` so it's never undefined.

Comment: Or `(backendData ?? []).map(...)`. If you're using a linter, this can sometimes be detected (highlighted as *"`backendData` is possibly `undefined`"*), and `undefinied.map()` is not valid code. Define it as an empty array like M0nst3R suggests, or handle it at runtime with a fallback, etc.

Comment: Also, there is no need for `.then(response => response.data)` with `axios()`, that's a `fetch()` thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first render, the effect has not run yet, so `backendData` is the inital value passed to `useState`: `undefined`, in this case.

The component tries to call `map` on `undefined`, which causes the error.

To fix this, you could set the initial state to an empty array

```js
const [backendData, setData] = useState([]);
```

or use optional chaining to avoid calling `map` and immediately return `undefined` when `backendData` is `undefined`. Note that you should not use curly braces in order to directly return the JSX from `map`.

```js
{backendData?.map(child => (
  <tr key={child._id}>
    <td>{child.childName}</td>
    <td>{child.childAge}</td>
    <td>{child.roomNumber}</td>
    <td>temporary</td>
    <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
    <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
    <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
    <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
  </tr> 
))}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping using const [backendData, setData] = useState([]); fixed the error  using backendData.length > 0 did too aswell as backendData?. but for some reason only Unmitigated's code displayed the data

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your `backendData` variable has an initial value of undefined. React `useState()` hook accepts a parameter, which will be set as the initial value for the state variable.

Currently in your code, your react component will attempt to return your jsx even before your `useEffect` finishes your axios request. Since you aren't passing an initial value to your `useState()` hook, your `backendData` variable has an undefined value initially. And when trying to access the `.map()` function that you would use on an array, there is no such method that exists for your undefined data type.

Instead, do

```
const [backendData, setData] = useState([]);
```

This'll set the initial value of `backendData` to an empty array. And when your `backendData.map()` function runs now, there will be no error because there is now an empty array to map over.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the below code (map )in JSX runs before the response of API. So you can resolve it by putting ? before map. Like this

```
 {backendData?.map(child => {
          <tr key={child._id}>
            <td>{child.childName}</td>
            <td>{child.childAge}</td>
            <td>{child.roomNumber}</td>
            <td>temporary</td>
            <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
            <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
            <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
            <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
          </tr> 
        })}
```

**OR**

```
 {backendData?.length > 0 && backendData.map(child => {
          <tr key={child._id}>
            <td>{child.childName}</td>
            <td>{child.childAge}</td>
            <td>{child.roomNumber}</td>
            <td>temporary</td>
            <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
            <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
            <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
            <td><img src={child.parentSignature} /></td>
          </tr> 
        })}
```

Answer (score 1):

When rendering your backendData state with the "map" method you're assuming you're reading through an **array** or a **list**. But you're declaring a state with an initial value of **undefined**.

An easy fix to this issue would be redeclaring your state as follows:

```
const [backendData, setData] = useState([]);
```

Instead of:

```
let [backendData, setData] = useState();
```

Answer (score 0):

How i solved this issue:

```
    const [user, setUser] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8081/login")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data); // debugging
        // Set user to res.data.user if it's an array, else set to an empty array
        setUser(Array.isArray(res.data.data) ? res.data.data : []);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  const userDetails = user.map((item) => (
    <tr key={item.id}>
      <td>{item.id}</td>
      <td>{item.name}</td>
      <td>{item.email}</td>
      <td>{item.password}</td>
      <td>
```